# Why would someone who thought they will work until they die contribute to a pension plan?

Tags: united-kingdom, contribution, pension

One of the shocking graphs going round at the moment is from [many millennials expect to work until they die](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/31/many-millennials-expect-to-work-until-they-die.html):

[image]

Now I'm a UK millennial who wants to retire early, however if I did think I were going to work until I die, **why do I have to contribute* to a pension plan at all?**

---

*According to [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/workplace-pensions/what-you-your-employer-and-the-government-pay) I have to put in, and that contribution rate will rise to 4% of my qualifying earnings:

> The law says a minimum percentage of your ‘qualifying earnings’ must be paid into your workplace pension scheme.

and

> The minimum you pay: 0.8% of your ‘qualifying earnings’ rising to 4% by 2018

Comment: Its weird how you are concentrating on a Japan stat, but on UK laws.  88% of UKers expect to retire.  That would make a defined benefit plan a good idea.  Sorry I have to down vote.

Comment: @PeteB.: No I'm focusing on UK laws because I'm from the UK. It still leaves 12% of UK millennials expecting to work until they die. I can edit out the graph and just quote the UK stat if you suggest that?

Comment: This may be a US-specific interpretation...but my father worked until he died (in his early 60s), and ~20 years later, my mother is still collecting his pension. That may or may not be relevant to pensions as they exist in other parts of the world, but "...so that your spouse will have income after you die" seems like a fair response, in my parents' case. Pensions, though, strike me as a bit like insurance....everyone pays in, some get less out than they paid on, some get more.

Comment: I would note that people are really, incredibly bad at affective forecasting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affective_forecasting Trying to draw meaning out of what 18-34 year olds think they will be willing and able to do in their 60s-70s+ should considered with extreme skepticism. If 18 year old me had so little understanding of what 30-year old me would be doing and enjoying, how is 30-year old me suppose to seriously know what 60-year old me will want?

Comment: As you get older and your faculties start to give up you may not be able to earn a living whether you want to or not. Plus: expecting to work and planning to work are two different things.

Comment: All workplaces in the UK offer a pension plan?!?!

Comment: Adding to this thread - my grandparents are 'working' in their 90's by continuing their research, publishing books etc. I certenly expect to work while I retire - however it may be just as well non-profit work for fun (or for nominal income) instead of full-time employment depending on ones willingness, health etc. This is probably popular atitude for those who consider work self-realisation instead of chore.

Comment: It is amazing they think this considering the number of 45+ people who can't find any work.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - From the UK government pensions website: "A new law means that every employer must automatically enrol workers into a workplace pension scheme"

Comment: nice to see my country has it's shit right on something atleast. what a boring life that would be, to not be able to enjoy retirement...

Comment: @SeanR The US has a similar scheme; we call it Social Security. We receive 100% benefits at age 66 but we can continue working if we wish. Maybe the UK has similar rules?

Comment: @monkeyZeus We have a 'National Insurance' scheme for a State Pension, paid at a similar age, which is automatically deducted by employers - however, there is also the new rules to have a private workplace pension too.

Comment: Interesting to see a typo in the graphic from a major news source that spell check should have caught.

Comment: The **reason** why contributing to a pension is required by law is precisely *because many people ask this question*!  Most people who want to work in their old age will not be able to (earn a decent amount), and if they (foolishly) do not contribute to a pension plan, they will become wards of the state.  If the state can prevent that by law, it's probably better for everyone.  It's certainly better for the state.  Also, even if people expect to need to work to maintain a lifestyle they *want*, if they're unable to work, at least they will be able to have **some** kind of lifestyle.

Comment: I think the biggest leap in logic here is assuming that people who respond "I expect to work until I die" are *happy* with that answer. I presume that in the vast majority of cases, people would wish to retire, but expect that they will not be able to, for financial reasons. So contributing to a pension plan would be to avoid these unhappy expectations from taking place.

Comment: "Now I'm a UK millennial who wants to retire early" - Good for you. Lots of people want to retire early. But wanting to retire early doesn't actually guarantee early retirement. Most of the answers talk about what could happen if you don't save enough for retirement, but even the savings themselves won't guarantee retirement either if you chose the wrong investments or the economy hits the doldrums. Even if you want to retire, you might not be *able* to.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Why? Simply: because it has been mandated as **law**, and so you may have no choice in the matter whether to contribute or not. Quoting from [GOV.UK – Workplace pensions](https://www.gov.uk/workplace-pensions/about-workplace-pensions):

> **‘Automatic enrolment’**
>
> A new law means that every employer must automatically enrol workers
>   into a workplace pension scheme if they:
>
> - are aged between 22 and State Pension age
> - earn more than £10,000 a year
> - work in the UK

Next: even if you think you will work "until you die", you can still access the money saved in the pension scheme when you attain the required minimum age for withdrawals under your scheme. For instance, that may be age 55, but it may also vary by scheme.

Becoming fully retired — as in **stopping all work** — is *not* a requirement to access retirement income from your pension scheme. In the eyes of a pension scheme, *retirement* is typically when you elect to take your income benefits according to the established rules of the scheme. Quoting from [nidirect – Working past State Pension age](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/working-past-state-pension-age):

> **Continuing in work and your workplace pension**
>
> If you reached the age at which you can start claiming your workplace
>   pension scheme, you don't need to stop work in order to claim. You have
>   a number of options, including taking some of the pension you've built
>   up while continuing to work for the same employer.

As to why things are set up this way: While some younger folk may, today, *expect* to continue working until death, for a variety of reasons that isn't always possible. Two typical such reasons are: disability, and involuntary unemployment (i.e. willing and able but still can't land the next job). Moreover, **plans change**. Young workers with health and vitality may expect they'll always feel invincible, but end up learning otherwise over time, and may come to appreciate the savings that were forced upon them.

The "forced savings" aspect of state and state-sponsored pension schemes are meant to provide **some** safety net for those later years when it is a strong possibility that one can't continue to work. The alternative is to be a 100% burden on family and/or society.

Comment: +1.  It is sort of like asking "Why would I buy car insurance if I never plan on getting into a car accident?"  Like a car accident, employment is something that is only partially under your control.

Comment: This goes double for the US - we legally have to contribute 6.2% to Social Security (matched by the employer, so a net 12.4%). Plus another 1.45% (also matched, 2.9% total) for Medicare. And the better you do financially, the more you contribute and the less you get paid on retiring. Most US millennials expect to never see most of their SS or Medicare contributions ever again.

Comment: "no choice in the matter whether to contribute or not" is not correct. Yes, you don't have a choice on whether you're enrolled, your employer must enroll you, but you can choose to opt out after enrollment. I'm not saying people should opt out, I'd encourage everyone to contribute to a pension, I'm just pointing out that line is wrong.

Comment: @brichins in the UK we pay both National Insurance and Income Tax on our earnings.  The use of those two revenue streams is much more arbitrary nowadays but historically I believe that NI was for the National Health Service and State Pension.  I know your years of NI contributions currently affect what state benefits you can draw (in terms of disability, etc) and what state pension you get at retirement.  The UK's NI might be like the US's Social Security payments in some ways.  Now we are also being enrolled in (private) workplace pension schemes.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Interesting point; thanks.I will update my answer once I've checked the facts about opt out potential.

Comment: @brichins US social security tax is capped at around $7k/yr. That is, if you make more than about $118k in wages, you will not pay social security tax on the wages over the limit. Further, social security is not means tested. The higher your average contribution, the higher your monthly benefit will be. Whether or not you see the full amount of your contribution in benefits depends on how long you live.

Comment: @brichins This is not true - SS is more 'forced savings' than 'tax'. You receive money when you retire based on how much you put in. The 'tax' part comes into play when total SS funds available are unable to pay out at the promised rate. Typically retirement funds have been often set up as **light** ponzi schemes, where an expectation of an ever-growing workforce helps to make high rates of defined benefits achievable. Where this fails is when the workforce declines relative to those in retirement; not sure where the extra money will come from then (if it comes at all).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon without doing down the political rabbit hole... the money is taken directly from workers paychecks, no opting out - "tax". It doesn't go to a personal account or even a dedicated central fund, so it's hardly a "savings" contribution. SS participants can't withdraw it on their own terms, and earning over a relatively small amount in retirement years means their SS benefit is reduced (by 50% of the income overage) until it disappears. A mandatory IRA, on the other hand, would belong to participants, be invested & grow, and pass on to their heirs.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Correct, earning / contributing more during working years means a larger benefit. I meant that if you continue to do well financially after retiring (i.e. keep working more than a hobby or part time) your SS benefit is reduced or even eliminated. Even if one retires fully, you'd have to live a long time to recover all the contribution. And you'll never get paid out what an investment account would have built up to.

Comment: Not sure what the law is in UK, but in US, there is shielding of retirement accounts from legal action.  Get a legal judgement against you and your normal savings are fair game.  Retirement accounts are shielded.

Comment: Whoa... they actually spell "enroll" with one ell. That is really, really bizarre to me!

Comment: @BrenBarn, «sort of like asking "Why would I buy car insurance if I never plan on getting into a car accident?"» except that car insurance companies generally pay. For instance, I am an Italian 24 years old and I **already know** that my retirement money is going to pay the current elderly people retirement. But by the time it will be my turn there will be no more money because the system is basically broken (likely, the Italian public insurance company will go bankrupt before that day).

Comment: @brichins: the reduction for working does not happen after a certain age.

Answer (score 15):

1. Even if you *expect* to work you might not be able to due to health reasons or economic factors that make it difficult to obtain employment, so it's good to have a safety-net.
2. A pension scheme, especially if it's tax-advantaged or there's a company-match, can be a useful savings scheme.  So even if you're still working when you reach normal retirement age, it provides you with a handy pot of money you can use for travel, recreation, or whatever.
3. As others have mentioned, the pension might benefit other family members such as a spouse or children.
4. You might change your mind about working until you drop.
5. With NHS cuts and austerity you might need the money to supplement whatever care benefits you're entitled to when you do fall ill in your old age.

Comment: Point 2 is a big one in the UK. Employers are now required to automatically enrol their employees in a pension scheme and to contribute to it. Combine the employee contributions with the tax advantages and you lose a lot of money by opting out.

Answer (score 6):

I would look at the wording of the question.  "Expect" does not necessarily mean that they *plan* to work until they die, or that they *want* to work until they die.

"Expect" here likely means that they *think they will have to* work until they die - in particular, think that they will not be able to save up enough to retire.  Thinking that you will have to work until you die doesn't mean you shouldn't save money - that's just giving up if you don't, right?  Instead you save up money and hopefully you're one of the luckier ones.

Answer (score 6):

The thing you appear to neglect is that: **Many people don't have a choice of when they retire.**

- They get sick
- They break a leg or arm or physically can't work anymore
- They get laid off and employers don't want to hire a senior citizen (ex. because they require larger salaries)
- They get laid off but can't find a comparable job
- Etc...

Another issue is that "work 'til I die" people are often 20-50 years old. If they changed their minds or were forced to retire (see above) or came to a realization later in life that they would like to retire, they've missed their chance. They've lost decades of compounding interest because they thought they knew everything in the world when they were 23. Forced retire savings hedges this 'common' mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to make two points:

**To focus on your test case of Japan**.  You point out that about a third of them believe they'll work until they die.  That means more than a majority of them believe they'll retire.  In a democracy where a majority of people make decisions it is completely expected that the majority will dictate the policy.  Of course there is fuzziness around that last statement because people who believe they'll retire could very well be of the mindset that they'll handle their retirement savings themselves rather than rely on government.  Similarly some people that expect to work until they die might realize that there's a risk that they won't be able to.

**To focus on the case of government run pensions.**  The pension program that a government runs isn't like a private savings plan where its purpose is to get you a good rate of return.  At best it's an insurance policy; more accurately it's just a tax and you should think of it this way.  The reason you should think of it that way is several fold.  One, if the pension fund is ever short, the government will make up the difference from the general fund.  Two, the government can spend the money from the pension fund on other programs if the law changes which, over the course of a lifetime, is entirely possible.  Three, no one has a legal right to withdraw their contributions directly.  Four, the point of the program is to take care of old people so they aren't starving in the street.  To do this, they take the money of the young and give it to to old people.  The money you pay in doesn't go to investments of any sort, it goes directly to the elderly.  Ultimately this is why you can't opt-out and why you should think of those contributions as a tax and not as savings.

Comment: Your first point is good. Your second point is misguided: although there is a state pension in the UK, the OP is actually writing about the government-mandated personal contributions into a private pension. The (not officially stated, I believe) aim is that the government can eventually only pay state pension to a low percentage of retirees, as it wants most people to have saved enough themselves.

Comment: The worst part about democracy is where the majority forces their opinions upon the minority, where there is no clear requirement for unanimity in the solution.

Comment: @AndyT That's a potentially a good point.  I can't quickly find information as to what happens on the backend to completely concede the point.  What kind of taxes/fees are on the mandatory savings themselves?  Are they only allowed to buy gov't bonds?  If no, what happens to people that get wiped out?  How are defined benefit schemes funded?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor - Ok, you have a lot of questions. General info on state pension is [here](https://www.gov.uk/new-state-pension), general info on workplace pensions (the gov mandated private pension) is [here](https://www.gov.uk/workplace-pensions).

Comment: Direct answers to your questions: Contributions into the workplace pension are free from income tax, depending on how your employer sets it up they may or may not be free from National Insurance (UK equivalent of social security). Workplace pensions normally invest in the stock market through hedge funds. If your workplace/private pension gets wiped out, you'll only have the state pension (which is paid for by National Insurance).

Comment: Defined benefit schemes are another thing altogether, and are very rarely available to new entrants these days. In theory they're funded by contributions from people still working, in practice many companies have to take money out of profits to make up shortfalls in defined benefit schemes.